# Calculate the fastest 5000 m time for the entire track

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have a cycling computer logging every second how far I've gone

A simplified version of the data looks like this:

```
 declare @DistanceTable Table
    (
      ID int,
      Time DateTime2,
      DistanceMeters float
    )

insert into @DistanceTable   values 
    (1, '2018-08-10 07:17:48', 3.8099999427795410),
    (2, '2018-08-10 07:17:49', 7.7600002288818359),
    (3, '2018-08-10 07:17:50', 12.3299999237060547),
    (4, '2018-08-10 07:17:51', 18.0000000000000000),
    (5, '2018-08-10 07:17:52', 24.8999996185302734),
    (6, '2018-08-10 07:17:53', 32.1599998474121094),
    (7, '2018-08-10 07:17:54', 40.7200012207031250),
    (8, '2018-08-10 07:17:55', 49.7599983215332031),
    (9, '2018-08-10 07:17:57', 68.6100006103515625),
    (10, '2018-08-10 07:17:58', 79.3199996948242188),
    (11, '2018-08-10 07:18:00', 100.1900024414062500),
    (12, '2018-08-10 07:18:02', 122.7099990844726563),
    (13, '2018-08-10 07:18:03', 134.1900024414062500),
    (14, '2018-08-10 07:18:04', 145.9199981689453125),
    (15, '2018-08-10 07:18:05', 158.4700012207031250),

    (16, '2018-08-10 07:24:04', 5003.4101562500000000), --5000 meters driven 
    (17, '2018-08-10 07:24:05', 5018.7797851562500000),
    (18, '2018-08-10 07:24:06', 5034.0498046875000000),
    (19, '2018-08-10 07:24:07', 5048.8901367187500000),
    (20, '2018-08-10 07:24:08', 5063.8798828125000000),
    (21, '2018-08-10 07:24:09', 5079.0200195312500000),
    (22, '2018-08-10 07:24:13', 5141.0600585937500000),
    (23, '2018-08-10 07:24:17', 5201.7500000000000000),
    (24, '2018-08-10 07:24:21', 5261.8798828125000000),
    (25, '2018-08-10 07:24:23', 5290.2900390625000000),
    (26, '2018-08-10 07:24:28', 5363.7099609375000000),
    (27, '2018-08-10 07:24:33', 5435.9101562500000000),
    (28, '2018-08-10 07:24:34', 5450.8901367187500000),
    (29, '2018-08-10 07:24:35', 5465.4199218750000000),
    (30, '2018-08-10 07:24:36', 5480.5400390625000000)
```

I'm trying to calculate the fastest 5000 m time for the entire track

So I want to calculate the time for the last 5000 meters for each record after 5000 m are driven

Comment: Why do you have two different preceeding distances for 5003.41015265? What exactly do you want the results to be for your sample table?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate the fastest 5000m time

Comment: Why do you have two different results for the same row in your sample results?

Comment: And if you want *fastest* time (Which you don't mention in your question), shouldn't you be looking at the time column?

Comment: @Shawn you got a very fair point. 

I'll update the question

Comment: Expected results according to the data provided please.

Comment: Since speed is a measurement of distance in relation to time. I'd start thinking about elapsed time at the same time as elapsed distance to begin with..

Comment: Also if you record something every second - the datetime is almost immaterial, the id will act as a second

Comment: @JGFMK the ID was added for thid question in order for refering to a record

Comment: But if a record gets added every second - the id itself will be like a second hand on a clock face

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem that you have is that the difference is never *exactly* 5,000 meters.  One approximation is to get the first value beyond 5,000 meters and use this for the calculation:

```
select top (1) dt.*, dt2.distance, dt2.time,
       (dt2.distance - dt.distance) as actual_distance,
       datediff(second, dt.time, dt2.time) as actual_time,
       (dt2.distance - dt.distance) / datediff(second, dt.time, dt2.time) as rate
from @DistanceTable dt cross apply
     (select top (1) dt2.*
      from @DistanceTable dt2
      where dt2.distance >= dt.distance + 5000 
      order by dt2.distance asc
     ) dt2
order by rate desc;
```

Your data points are close enough that the actual total distance would be like 5,009 meters, 5,002 meters and so on.  That is probably good enough, so I'll stop here.

Actually interpolating the first and last legs to get an exact result is possible, but it would be a lot of effort for a very small improvement.

Comment: Only problem are when you are having lige 5000 records in your dataset it becomes extremly slow. I belive I have to implement it int C#